# Start with 10 user and add every 5 min 50 user gatling scala

Tags: scala, performance, gatling

I am beginner in GATLING. I want to execute performance scenarios with below expectations:

Start with 10 user and add every 5 min 50 user. This means:

- 0 min: 10 user (at once)
- 5 - 10 min: 60 user
- 10 - 15 min: 110 user
- 15 - 20 min: 160 user

below is my simulation setup:

```
setUp(Scenarios.inject(
    nothingFor(5 seconds),
    atOnceUsers(Environment.atOnceusersCount.toInt),
    rampUsers(Environment.rampUsersCount.toInt) during (Environment.durationForRampusers.toInt seconds)

  )

where rampUsersCount = 2
durationForRampusers = 10 seconds
```

I want to understand how to increase `rampUsers` count gradually.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refrain from giving your questions a sense of urgency. Everyone who may answer you does it on their free time and on their terms. For further details, please read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use either `incrementUsersPerSec` or `incrementConcurrentUsers`, depending on if you want an open or closed workload model, see [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/#meta-dsl).